# Is it possible to use Vue and Vue component in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vue.js, vuetify.js, blazor

I wish to use Vue/Vuetify components in Blazor as I am hooked to it because its robust.

I have tried this but no luck.

```
<body>
<div id="app">Loading...</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        message: 'Hello from Vue!'
    })
</script>
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/" 
<h1>Hello, world!</h1> 
Welcome to your new app.
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<p>{{ message }}</p>
```

Is there a trick or workaround to run Vue within Blazor?

Comment: I am hooked in a way that Vue has Vuetify which is really a nice UI library. And I wonder if same is possible with what they did in React to Blazor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61487266/render-react-component-inside-blazor-page .Btw, I would be more glad if your answer encourages imagination and not instantly shutting down possibilities and innovation.

Comment: Blazor and Vue both use a virtual DOM to generate HTML and work out what elements to change. Using both together is a *bad* idea and should be avoided unless you really know what you're doing (e.g. the Vue and Blazor content areas _never_ overlap). A bit like having two artists paint the same picture on the same canvas. If they stick to their own bits its fine, otherwise they start painting over the other's work.

Answer (score 4):

```
<!-- wwwroot/index.html -->
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  window.newVueApp = function () {
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        counter: 0,
      },
      methods: {
        increment() {
          this.counter++;
        },
      },
    });
  };
</script>
```

```
<!-- Shared/MainLayout.razor -->
<div class="content px-4" id="app" v-cloak>
    @Body
</div>
...
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("newVueApp");
    }
}
```

```
<!-- Pages/Index.razor -->
<p>counter: {{ counter }}</p>

<button @click="increment">Increase counter</button>
```

The updated sample project is [here](https://github.com/ChrisWong979/BlazorWebAssemblyHelloVue).

Comment: Update my answer and create another project. Please try it. I am not familiar with Blazor, but it seems that it allows other Javascript libraries.

Comment: Yea. Blazor has it. The example thu creates problem in routes.